# Query Error when trying to run query

Tags: mysql-5.7

Please bear with me as I am relatively new to SQL. I am using MySQL and trying to run a query against a DB with two tables ('Network', and 'Server'). When I trying a portion of the query it executes without fail, however, when I try and add to it, I receive nothing but errors ranging from 1046 to 1140 to 1241. I am sure it is a matter of syntax and formatting, but I cannot figure it out. Please help. Below is my query:

```
SELECT (SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(server.Tech=7)/COUNT(server.Tech) * 100,2), '%') AS Server,
       CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(network.Tech=7)/COUNT(network.Tech) * 100,2), '%') AS Network
           FROM network join server) AS V,
    (SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(server.Tech=2)/COUNT(server.Tech) * 100,2), '%') AS Server,
       CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(network.Tech=2)/COUNT(network.Tech) * 100,2), '%') AS Network
           FROM network join server) AS J
    (SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(server.Tech=4)/COUNT(server.Tech) * 100,2), '%') AS Server,
       CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(network.Tech=4)/COUNT(network.Tech) * 100,2), '%') AS Network
           FROM network join server) AS K
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the tables on a value.  I'm taking a wild guess here, but I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(server.Tech=7)/COUNT(server.Tech) * 100,2), '%') AS Server,
CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(network.Tech=7)/COUNT(network.Tech) * 100,2), '%') AS Network
           FROM network join server

On network.Tech = server.Tech

) AS V,
```

I don't know what your equals sign is doing in your arithmetic operation.  Are you trying to pull all Tech where it equals 7?  If so, it would be

```
SELECT (SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(server.Tech)/COUNT(server.Tech) * 100,2), '%') AS Server,
CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(network.Tech)/COUNT(network.Tech) * 100,2), '%') AS Network
           FROM network join server

On network.Tech = server.Tech
WHERE server.Tech = 7 AND network.Tech=7

) AS V,
```

Of course, if you are trying to sum all Techs that equal 7 over the full rowcount, it will need more work.

Comment: Ultimately I would like 3 columns in the out put with 3 rows (not including headers), The columns would be Tech, Server, Network. The rows would be the percentages for Tech 7, the percentages for Tech 4, and the percentages for Tech 2. The data is acquired by dividing number of Techs that = say 7 for the first row divided by the number of possible entries, and so on for the remaining rows. I hope that helps explain what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  Give me a few and I will post a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Without knowing your data structure, this should organize all of your techs without explicitly defining them in your code.

```
Declare @ServerRowCount Float = (Select Count(*) From Server)
Declare @NetworkRowCount Float = (Select Count(*) From Network)

Select S.Tech 
        ,Convert(nvarchar(5),Round(Count(S.Tech)/@ServerRowCount,2,10)*100) +'%' Server
        ,N.Network Network
From Server S
Join  
(Select Tech 
        ,Convert(nvarchar(5),Round(Count(Tech)/@NetworkRowCount,2,10)*100) +'%' Network 
From Network
Group by Tech
) N
On S.Tech = N.Tech
Group By S.Tech, N.Network
```

Comment: If you need to define them, just use a WHERE clause in the appropriate places.

Comment: Am I missing something, I get a error code 1064 when trying to use the code you have listed above. When I look deeper it says that Declare is not valid at this position. I did some digging and it says that declare must be used inside a BEGIN...END statement. However, I can't seem to get that right either.

Comment: I just realized you were using MySQL.  The above is T-SQL, which did parse in SSMS.  I do not have a MySQL parser, but you should able to replace the Declares using something like:  Set @ServerRowCount = (Select Count(*) From Server) without an explicit Declare.

Also, I'm not sure if the '+' will concatenate in MySQL, so this may have to be worked back into a CONCAT command.  Sorry about the confusion.  The logic of the operation works quite well, but I may have to leave the syntax to someone more familiar with MySQL.